# Argo Workflow - DAG Task level retry

Tags: argo-workflows

I have a DAG workflow as below

`taskA -> after taskA completes taskB and taskC runs in parallel -> once task B and C completes taskD starts`. In case taskC fails due to some external issue which needs a manual intervention for correction. After correction can we manually restart (from UI or CLI) the workflow so that it resumes directly from the failed taskC and goes to taskD and completes the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, clicking 'retry' from the workflow in the GUI **will do just that**.

Comment: I don’t think there is task-level retry in the UI. To get it to restart at the failed task, they’d need to use memoization.

Comment: The workflow level retry will only retry failed tasks. It won't retry tasks that are successful. Memoization is for detecting if the same tasks has been run before even in another workflow and is not necessary for what the OP wants.